# In the context of git (and diff), what is a "hunk"

Tags: git, diff

I was looking for a definition of "hunk" while reading some git documentation.

I know it means a description of the difference between two files and that it has a well defined format, but I couldn't call to mind a succinct definition.

I tried searching with google, but there were a lot of somewhat spurious hits.

Comment: "I was looking for a definition of "hunk" while reading some git documentation" - have you _seen_ Linus Torvalds when he's modelling for his beachwear line?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

And eventually I found this:

> When comparing two files, diff finds sequences of lines common to both files, interspersed with groups of differing lines called hunks.

here:
http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Hunks.html

Which was exactly the kind of succinct definition I was looking for.  Hopefully this helps someone else out!

Comment: you can see the hunks with 'git diff --no-ext-diff'  if you have modified files.

Answer (score 37):

The term "hunk" is indeed not specific to Git, and comes from the [Gnu diffutil format](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Detailed-Unified.html). Even more succinctly:

> Each hunk shows one area where the files differ.

But the challenge for Git is to determine the right *boundaries* for a hunk.

The rest of the answer helps illustrates what a hunk looks like in Git:

After various heuristics (like the [compaction one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41665589/6309), which is gone in Git 2.12), Git maintainers settled on the indent one, which was introduced in [Sept. 2016 with Git 2.11, commit 433860f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/433860f3d0beb0c6f205290bd16cda413148f098).

> Some groups of added/deleted lines in diffs can be slid up or down,
> because lines at the edges of the group are not unique. **Picking good shifts for such groups is not a matter of correctness but definitely has a big effect on aesthetics**.
> For example, consider the following two diffs.
> The first is what standard Git emits:
>
> ```
> --- a/9c572b21dd090a1e5c5bb397053bf8043ffe7fb4:git-send-email.perl
> +++ b/6dcfa306f2b67b733a7eb2d7ded1bc9987809edb:git-send-email.perl
> @@ -231,6 +231,9 @@ if (!defined $initial_reply_to && $prompting) {
>  }
>
>  if (!$smtp_server) {
> +       $smtp_server = $repo->config('sendemail.smtpserver');
> +}
> +if (!$smtp_server) {
>         foreach (qw( /usr/sbin/sendmail /usr/lib/sendmail )) {
>                 if (-x $_) {
>                         $smtp_server = $_;
> ```
>
> The following diff is equivalent, but is obviously preferable from an
> aesthetic point of view:
>
> ```
> --- a/9c572b21dd090a1e5c5bb397053bf8043ffe7fb4:git-send-email.perl
> +++ b/6dcfa306f2b67b733a7eb2d7ded1bc9987809edb:git-send-email.perl
> @@ -230,6 +230,9 @@ if (!defined $initial_reply_to && $prompting) {
>         $initial_reply_to =~ s/(^\s+|\s+$)//g;
>  }
>
> +if (!$smtp_server) {
> +       $smtp_server = $repo->config('sendemail.smtpserver');
> +}
>  if (!$smtp_server) {
>         foreach (qw( /usr/sbin/sendmail /usr/lib/sendmail )) {
>                 if (-x $_) {
> ```
>
> This patch teaches Git to pick better positions for such "diff sliders" using heuristics that take the positions of nearby blank lines **and the indentation of nearby lines into account**.

---

With Git 2.14 (Q3 2017), that indent heuristic will be the default!

See [commit 1fa8a66](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1fa8a66bf76953c6fb9cfe5e17b26a3a0920f538) (08 May 2017) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit 33de716](https://github.com/git/git/commit/33de7163879ca83be7d6e1583c125f84e1e7c329) (08 May 2017) by [Stefan Beller (`stefanbeller`)](https://github.com/stefanbeller).
See [commit 37590ce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/37590ce3c535f92e28da83893f843cc0099873bf), [commit cf5e772](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cf5e77223a012737930e1bbacc85c6423b03af77) (08 May 2017) by Marc Branchaud.
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 53083f8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/53083f8547cd45cdfabcf2f1bd21461cd6769189), 05 Jun 2017)</sup>

> ### diff: enable indent heuristic by default
>
> The feature was included in v2.11 (released 2016-11-29) and we got no negative feedback. Quite the opposite, all feedback we got was positive.
>
> Turn it on by default. Users who dislike the feature can turn it off
> by setting `diff.indentHeuristic`.

---

With Git 2.24 (Q4 2019), the "indent heuristics" that decides where to split
diff hunks has seen its documentation corrected.

See [commit 64e5e1f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/64e5e1fba11e6abf5572150e7cd2ba9afb66d6ce) (15 Aug 2019) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e115170](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e1151704f22ce3de778527047ecfd033e6f1aa83), 09 Sep 2019)</sup>

> ### diff: 'diff.indentHeuristic' is no longer experimental
>
> The indent heuristic started out as experimental, but it's now our
> default diff heuristic since [33de716](https://github.com/git/git/commit/33de7163879ca83be7d6e1583c125f84e1e7c329) (`diff`: enable indent heuristic
> by default, 2017-05-08, Git v2.14.0-rc0).
> Alas, that commit didn't update the documentation, and the description of the '`diff.indentHeuristic`' configuration variable still implies that it's experimental and not the default.
>
> Update the description of '`diff.indentHeuristic`' to make it clear that it's the default diff heuristic.
>
> The description of the related '`--indent-heuristic`' option has already
> been updated [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41665589/6309).

[The documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/64e5e1fba11e6abf5572150e7cd2ba9afb66d6ce/Documentation/config/diff.txt#L190-L192) will now read:

> ### `diff.indentHeuristic`:
>
> Set this option to `false` to disable the default heuristics that shift diff hunk boundaries to make patches easier to read.

---

With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), you don't even have to specify `--indent-heuristic` anymore (since it is the default for quite some times now).

See [commit 44ae131](https://github.com/git/git/commit/44ae131e3848a290b165ff0efffa1c504034f776) (28 Oct 2019) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 532d983](https://github.com/git/git/commit/532d983823b19e0f7c0df0a70abcb237a06b2870), 01 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`builtin/blame.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/44ae131e3848a290b165ff0efffa1c504034f776): remove '--indent-heuristic' from usage string
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: SZEDER Gábor</sup>
>
> The indent heuristic is our default diff heuristic since [33de716387](https://github.com/git/git/commit/33de7163879ca83be7d6e1583c125f84e1e7c329) ("`diff`: enable indent heuristic by default", 2017-05-08, Git v2.14.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/53083f8547cd45cdfabcf2f1bd21461cd6769189) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3a847d1dba7688435058d8d4161b3456bc1103d)), but the usage string of '`git blame`' still mentions it as "experimental heuristic".
>
> We could simply update the short help associated with the option, but according to the comment above the option's declaration it was "only included here to get included in the "`-h`" output".
>
> That made sense while the feature was still experimental and we wanted to give it more exposure, but nowadays it's unnecessary.
>
> So let's rather remove the '`--indent-heuristic`' option from '`git blame`'s usage string.
>
> Note that '`git blame`' will still accept this option, as it is parsed in `parse_revision_opt()`.
>
> Astute readers may notice that this patch removes a comment mentioning "the following two options", but it only removes one option.
>
> The reason is that the comment is outdated: that other options was '`--compaction-heuristic`', and it has already been removed in [3cde4e02ee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3cde4e02ee891bff53bac7f6a7d977f50418a4b5) (diff: retire "compaction" heuristics, 2016-12-23), but that commit forgot to update this comment.

Answer (score 0):

For your information, you can read this simple explanation also:
https://mvtechjourney.wordpress.com/2014/08/01/git-stage-hunk-and-discard-hunk-sourcetree/