# I want to git log a block of xml in a file that has been reordered

Tags: xml, git

I have a file with the structure

```
<parent>
  <child name='abc'>
    <grandchild/>
    <grandchild/>
    <grandchild/>
  </child>
  <child name='xyz'>
    <grandchild/>
    <grandchild/>
    <grandchild/>
  </child>
  ....
<parent>
```

A while back we decided to reorder the file but the blocks remained intact.

I have tried using

```
git log -L1994,1996:myfile.xml
```

this gave the following output which is close to what I am looking for
the problem being I was after 
in the current commit  is on lines 3784-3788

```
diff --git a/myFile.xml b/myFile.xml
--- a/myFile.xml
+++ b/myFile.xml

@@ -1336,4 +1903,4 @@
-    <child name="zzxxyy" >
-      <grandChild >...</grandChild>
-      <grandChild >...</grandChild>
+    <child name="aabbcc" >
+      <grandChild attr='...'/>
+      <grandChild >...</grandChild>
+      <grandChild >...</grandChild>

commit ###
Author: fred

ABC-456 blah blah blah

diff --git a/myFile.xml b/myFile.xml
--- a/myFile.xml
+++ b/myFile.xml
@@ -283,3 +283,4 @@
     <child name="zzxxyy" >
-      <grandChild attr="..."/>
+      <grandChild >...</grandChild>
+      <grandChild >...</grandChild>

commit ###
Author: fred

ABC-123 blah blah blah

diff --git a/myFile.xml b/myFile.xml
--- a/myFile.xml
+++ b/myFile.xml
@@ -249,0 +254,3 @@
+    <child name="zzxxyy" >
+      <grandChild attr="..."/>
```

I was hoping for it to track "aabbcc" back through the log.

e.g.

```
@@ -338,4 +1903,4 @@
-    <child name="aabbcc" >
-      <grandChild attr='...'/>
-      <grandChild >...</grandChild>
-      <grandChild >...</grandChild>
+    <child name="aabbcc" >
+      <grandChild attr='...'/>
+      <grandChild >...</grandChild>
+      <grandChild >...</grandChild>
```

But I expect that I am asking too much.

Using git version 2.12.2

Comment: Show your expected and actual outputs, and tell us WHY you think the output should be the way you show it.

Comment: Added a sanitised real world example is that enough? as to why questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435343/retrieve-the-commit-log-for-a-specific-line-in-a-file hint it may be possible.

Comment: What version of Git are you using? 2.11+? (as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44400027/6309)

Comment: git version 2.12.2

Comment: Do you still see the same issue (same git diff) with Git 2.17?

Comment: Yes same output. I think i am asking too much here and the reordering has confused log.