# How to show diff of two files but only show lines which have common starting string?

Tags: diff

How to find diff of two files but only show lines which have common starting string?

For example,
file1:

```
start1 1234
1234
start2 1234
```

file2:

```
start1 ABCD
ABCD
start2 ABCD
```

And the diff should be just:

```
> start1 1234
---
< start1 ABCD
> start2 1234
----
< start2 ABCD
```

or something like this:

```
start1
start2
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to script/code it yourself, because a classic diff (or [`git diff --no-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgt--no-index--ltpathgtltpathgt) which can be used with any two files outside of any Git repository) would display only hunks.

See "[In the context of git (and diff), what is a “hunk”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37620729/6309)": that would display *more* than just the different lines.

> diff finds sequences of lines common to both files, interspersed with groups of differing lines called hunks.