# Resolve `git merge master` conflicts after doing `git checkout master --patch`

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-checkout, git-merge-conflict

To be able to merge my local branch with `master` by a pull request, I'm trying to update my local branch with the latest modification on `master`. Since conflicts are complicated, I used this command to hand pick chunks of code modifications:

```
git checkout master --patch
```

Even after doing so, I cannot merge my local branch into `master` by a pull request due to conflicts. Also running this command, might *not* work due to complex conflicts:

```
git merge master
```

I ran out of options, how can I update my local branch with latest modifications on `master` without messing up anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem got resolved.

I run command

```
git checkout master --patch
```

and I inspect code [hunks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44400027/3405291) one by one. This way, my local branch becomes **reviewed** and **approved**. Having done so, I need to **keep the changes in my local branch** when doing final merge by [`-X ours`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21777677/3405291) option:

```
 git merge master -X ours
```

Then I can see the merge details by [`-m`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40986893/3405291) option just to double-check the merge:

```
git show -m 7060e
```

Now the merge is fine, even with complex conflicts. Now my pull request shows *no* conflicts anymore.