# How to merge changes from a commit below certain line?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-cherry-pick

I know you can merge/cherry-pick changes from a certain commit but is there a way to merge/cherry-pick changes from a commit but only below a certain line in code, e.g.: merge/cherry-pick changes from a commit 25gh4q1 but only below line 202?

Comment: No you can’t merge part of a file using git.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I think I've managed to find an answer although not doing precisely what I was asking, but achieving the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

it's not a one-liner but you could do this:

```
git cherry-pick 25gh4q1
git reset --mixed HEAD~
git add -p
<interactively stage only relevant parts of the file>
git commit
git reset --hard
```

explanation:

`git cherry-pick 25gh4q1` - cherry pick the whole commit, including the unwanted things

`git reset --mixed HEAD~` - keeps the files changed as in commit `25gh4q1` but they will now appear as "Changes not staged for commit"

`git add -p` - this allows to interactively stage only some of the changes, not all of them, including parts of files; `-p` stands for `patch`.

`git commit` - commit the staged changes

`git reset --hard` - clean up the unwanted parts of commit `25gh4q1` which haven't been staged or committed

Comment: I think `git checkout --patch` might be achieving the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout --patch <commit-tag-from-any-branch>
```

This will enter into a patching mode in witch we'll be able to see the commit divided into hunks (in git chunks of code are called hunks - see [In the context of git (and diff), what is a "hunk"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37620729/in-the-context-of-git-and-diff-what-is-a-hunk) for more details) and we'll be presented with options to operate on the hunks of the commit, e.g.: add them to the index, drop, move between hunks and more

[image]