# Why Git merge not working properly with local branch?

Tags: git, github

I have a local_branch which has local changes , I want my main branch to merge into it. But when I do “git merge origin/main” it shows me already upto date . But I am sure I am not as I can see some changes in main that I don’t have locally. It could also be that I accidentally resolved conflicts to mine and that’s why it is showing already up to date. How can I get out of this situation ? I want my local branch to merge the main branch

Answer (score 1):

> I have a local_branch which has local changes, I want my main branch to merge into it. But when I do “git merge origin/main” it shows me already up to date ...

That means exactly what it says: you've already merged `origin/main`, so there's no work left to do.

It's worth noting a number of things here:

- First, `git merge` does not mean *make same*.  If it did that, we would lose work!  Instead, it means *combine work*.
- Second, the definition of *work* and *combine* are tricky.  The "combine" part isn't that hard once you figure out what it means to "find work that has been done", but *that* part *is* kind of hard.
- Last, the "direction" of the merge matters somewhat, although less than most people think at first.  We'll see this below.

To understand why the definition of "work" is tricky, let's start with some very basic things you need to know about Git.

#### Git is about commits

Those new to Git often think that Git is about *files*, and it's not.  It's about *commits*.  Each commit *holds* files—if they didn't, Git would be useless—but what Git really cares about here is the *commit*.  You get all of a commit, or none of it: you never get half a commit.<sup>1</sup>

Those new to Git often think that Git is about *branches*, and it's not.  It's about *commits*.  Git organizes commits *into* branches, and we (humans) use *branch names* to have Git help us *find* the commits, but again, what Git really cares about here is the *commits*.

> Aside:  I also find that *branch* is a bad word in Git—not bad as in the kind of ["four-letter word"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-letter_word) profanity, but rather, bad as in nobody knows at first what you mean when you say *branch*, in the same way that *bad word* brings up profanity, or how ["bad" sometimes means "good"](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2015/12/bad.html).  That is, the word *branch* has multiple meanings in Git, and people will use this word in several sentences—or several times in *one* sentence—with each occurrence meaning something different!

So, okay, Git is about *commits*.  It's possible to use Git without having any branch names at all (but this is not a good idea, at least not if you're a human).  This means we need to know *exactly* what a commit is and does for you.  Let me start with this though:

- A Git *repository* is, at its heart, a collection of two databases, one usually much bigger than the other.
- The usually-bigger database holds Git's commits and other Git *objects* (supporting objects that let Git hold onto commits and/or make commits work better).  Everything in this big database is read-only, and the database itself is mostly (though not 100%) *append*-only.  That is, commits don't normally go away, and no commit, once made, can ever change.  Instead, we just *add new ones*.
- The objects in this big database are numbered, with big, ugly, random-looking *hash IDs* or (more formally) Git *object IDs* or *OIDs*.  These were exclusively SHA-1 hashes at one time (that's no longer true) so old documentation will call these SHAs and the like, too.  Git literally *needs* the hash ID (the OID) to *find* the object.  So every commit has a unique hash ID; that hash ID, in a sense, *is* the commit.
- The (usually smaller) second database holds *names:* branch names, tag names, remote-tracking names, and lots of other kinds of names.  Git provides these for us humans, for whom hash IDs are unusable except via cut-and-paste with the mouse or whatever.  Instead, we get to use things like branch names: a branch name like `main` or `develop` translates into a (one, single) hash ID, which—for a branch name—is *defined as* the *latest* commit that is "on" that branch.

Hence, by using these two databases, we can give Git a name (`local_branch` for instance, or `origin/main`).  Git will use that name to look up a commit hash ID as needed.  Git then uses the hash ID to look up the actual commit in the big all-Git-objects database.

When I say the commit's hash ID is *unique*, I really mean *unique:* we will "clone" a Git repository with `git clone`, for instance, and when we do, we *copy* all the Git objects from the other repository's database.  These copies have the *same* OIDs as the originals.  (That's why the objects are read-only: the OIDs are cryptographic checksums of the data.  Change the data, and you've changed the checksum and have a different object.  Since the objects database is largely append-only, all you have done is add a *new* object: the old one is still there, under the old ID.)

So that's what we need to know about the databases:

- The big one holds objects indexed by their hash IDs, including the commits.  That's how Git finds any specific commit: you give Git the hash ID and Git simply looks it up.  It's either there—the whole thing is there, never just some part of it—or it's not, and because it can't change, if you have a commit with some known hash ID, and someone else has something in some other Git repository with the *same* hash ID, you both necessarily have the *same commit*.<sup>2</sup>
- The little one means that most of the time, we don't *have* to use a raw hash ID: we can use a *name* and Git will look up the raw hash ID for us.

Now let's move on to the commit.  **A commit, in Git:**

- Is numbered, as we just saw.
- Contains two things: a *full snapshot of every file*, and some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.

On hearing that every commit has a full snapshot of every file, people often object: *Won't that make the repository grossly huge?*  It would, except that:

- the files in the snapshot are compressed, sometimes highly compressed; and
- the files are *de-duplicated*, which in many ways is even more important.

(Git achieves the de-duplication by storing each file's content as an *object* in the big objects database.  The high-degree-of-compression happens later in the game when objects become *packed* into a "pack file", which we won't cover at all here, as none of this matters for simply *using* Git.)

While the files are what we care about when we go to *do work*, right at the moment, it's actually the *metadata* we need to care about.  The metadata of any one given commit contain, among other things:

- a user name and email address for the person who made the commit;
- a date-and-time stamp;
- a log message, which `git log` can show or summarize; and
- crucially for Git's operation, a *list of previous commit hash IDs*.

This list is usually exactly one entry long.  The (single) commit hash ID thus stored in any given commit is called the *parent* of the commit.

This trick of storing a *parent* commit hash ID in each commit means that if we can find the *last* commit in some chain of commits, we can use that to work backwards.  Suppose `H` stands for the hash ID of the last commit in some chain of commits.  We say that the hash ID stored *in* `H` *points to* the previous commit—let's call it `G` for simplicity.  We can draw this like so:

```
        <-G <-H
```

That is, commit `H` is literally pointing backwards to commit `G`.  Of course, `G` is a commit too, so it too has a parent, which we can call `F`:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

and since `F` has a parent, Git can start at `H` and work back to `G` and then `F` and so on.  Eventually, all this working-backwards will come to the *very first commit ever*, which won't have a parent, because it can't.  Its list of parents, in its metadata, will be empty, and that gives us the whole chain:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H
```

(our repository apparently has just eight commits in it).

How do we find `H`?  We already know: we use a *branch name* like `main` to do that:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- main
```

Note that I have gotten a bit lazy about drawing the arrows between commits.  That's partly because they literally can't change—they're metadata *in* the commits, and no part of *any* commit can ever change—and also because of the more complicated graph I'm about to draw.

---

<sup>1</sup>A still-being-developed feature called *partial clone* lets you get "half" (or some fragment of) a commit, with a promise that the rest will appear later if/when needed.  This does a lot of damage to the way you *should* think about Git *initially*, so let's pretend it doesn't exist.  It's not really ready for the average user yet anyway.  Once it is, I believe it will be pretty seamless—that is, you won't have to be aware that it even exists—except for the fact that if your network is down and you *have* a partial commit when you need a *full* one, your Git will simply stop working at that point.  If your network is up, your Git software will just get slower (and maybe print out progress messages about downloading stuff).

<sup>2</sup>This literally *can't* work forever, and won't.  In theory, the size of the hash ID puts the day of failure far enough into the future that we don't care.  [There's a flaw in this theory, but it is being addressed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452).

---

#### Branches, of several kinds

Suppose we take our simple, relatively new Git repository with a mere eight commits and one branch name `main`, and add *two more* branch names, `br1`, and `br2`.  A *branch name* in Git *must store exactly one hash ID*; that's the hash ID of the commit that is the *last* commit "on" or "in" the branch.  If we make all three names point to `H`, we get:

```
...--G--H   <-- br1, br2, main
```

Right now, it doesn't matter which *name* we use, since all three point to `H`.  But in a moment that won't be true.  To remember which *name* we're using, let's attach the special name `HEAD`, written in all uppercase like this, to exactly one branch name:

```
...--G--H   <-- br1, br2, main (HEAD)
```

This says we're using the name `main` to find commit `H`.

If we now run:

```
git switch br1     # or git checkout br1
```

we're telling Git to switch from branch `main`, i.e., commit `H`, to branch `br1`, i.e., commit `H`.  We aren't changing *commits*—which we'll see in a moment is pretty important—but we are changing *branches*.  We now have:

```
...--G--H   <-- br1 (HEAD), br2, main
```

Let's make a new commit now.  We'll come back in a moment to some important things about making new commits, but for now let's just assume that this makes a new snapshot-and-metadata (it does) and let's call this new commit `I`.  Git will arrange for new commit `I` to point backwards to existing commit `H`:

```
          I
         /
...--G--H
```

and then, as the last step of `git commit`, Git will *write `I`'s hash ID, whatever that is, into the name `br1`* so that we have:

```
          I   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2, main
```

That is, the *current branch name*—which we find by seeing which name `HEAD` is attached to—gets updated to point to the *new commit*.  The new commit is now the *last* commit on the branch.  If we make another new commit, we get:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2, main
```

Commits `I-J` are only "on" branch `br1` right now.  Commits up through `H` are on *all three* branches right now.

I keep saying *right now* because, in part:

- we can, at any time, add *new names*, using `git branch` for instance;
- we can, at any time, *delete* branch names, also using `git branch` (with -d`or`-D`); and
- we can, at any time, *move* any branch name, using either `git branch` or `git reset` with various options.

Whatever commit a branch name points to, that's the *last* commit that is in that branch.  Other commits that we can find by moving backwards, through the parents, are also "in" the branch, and many commits are generally in many branches, with the very first commit usually being in *every* branch.

Anyway, let's `git switch br2` now, or `git checkout br2`, and run `git branch -d main`, to get this:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

The name `main` is completely gone (this makes it easier to draw the graph, there's no particular other reason to remove it here), but we don't need it: it just gives us a *fast* way to find commit `H`.  We have a slow way: we can find commit `J`, using name `br1`, and then work backwards two hops to `I` and then `H`.  And we have another fast way, right now: the name `br2` finds `H`.

Note that at this point, the files we had for commit `J` vanish, and are replaced with the files for commit `H`.  Changes we made seem to be gone!  But they're not gone: there's a full snapshot in commit `I`, and another in commit `J`, and if we `git switch br2` we get those files back (and the files from `H` vanish).  It's time to talk, briefly, about your *working tree* and *Git's index*.

#### Git's index and your working tree

We'll skim this quickly for space reasons, but it's important to know: A *standard* ("non-bare") repository includes a *working tree* or *work-tree*.  The repository proper is found inside the hidden `.git` directory (or folder, if you prefer that term) that you can find at the top of this working tree.  Inside this `.git` there are various control and auxiliary files that implement the two big databases and all the other stuff that Git wants to have.  You may look inside them, but in general you shouldn't change any of these files unless you really know what you're doing: Git is very fussy about its files in the `.git` repository proper.  It's a bad idea to store this in a cloud-synced folder, too, because cloud-syncing software and Git have very different ideas about what's important.  Cloud-syncing software *will* eventually damage a Git repository (and [Murphy's Law](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Efgandon/miscellaneous/murphy/) means this usually happens right before some big demo).  Don't do it; sync Git repositories using `git fetch` and `git push`.

The *working tree*, by contrast, holds the files that you see and work on / with.  We mentioned that a *commit* stores a full snapshot of every file (that Git knows about, at the time you, or whoever, make the snapshot), and that what's *in* a commit is in a special format that only Git can read and literally nothing can overwrite (not successfully, that is: *physically* overwriting will just damage the data since the hash ID won't match up any more: this is one way cloud syncing software breaks a repository).  But to get work done, we need regular (non-Git-ified) files that programs *can* read and write.  Git puts those files into our working tree: they can be *copied out of* a commit, like extracting an archive, and then we have ordinary files.

**Important:** The files *in* your working tree are *not in Git!*  They may have just come *out of* Git, but the files that *are* in Git (in commits) are the special Git-ified ones.  These are ordinary files; Git has nothing to do with them while you work on them, and if you remove one, Git *can't* get *that* one back.  Git can only get back the Git-ified ones in the commits.

If Git were like other version control systems, it would stop here: there would be committed files that are frozen for all time, and there would be your working tree files, which are yours to do with as you please.  There would be two copies of each "active" file: the frozen one in the current commit, and the one you're fiddling with.  Now and then you'd run `git commit` and Git would take those working tree files and freeze them.  But Git isn't like those other version control systems.  That's not how Git goes about making new commits.

Instead, Git has a *third* area—sort of *between* the commits and the working tree—where Git stores a *third copy*, in between the frozen copy in the commit and the usable copy in the working tree.  We might call this a "copy" rather than a copy, though.  This third "copy", the one in-between, is in something that Git calls the *index*, or the *staging area*, or—rarely these days—the *cache*.  The "copy" in the index is in the Git-ified and de-duplicated *format*, so at least initially, this "copy" never takes any space, because *it came out of the current commit*.

Remember that we ran `git switch br2` or whatever, and that's where we got the *commit* that Git used to fill in the working tree.  Git will *remove*, from your working tree and from its index, all the files that go with the commit you're moving away from.  Git will then place, into its index and your working tree, all the files that go with the commit you're moving *to*.  So when we have:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2
```

(and everything else is all "clean", as in there's no uncommitted work anywhere), Git's index and your working tree *match* commit `J`'s snapshot.  Then we run:

```
git switch br2
```

and Git *removes* the commit-`J` files and installs, instead, the commit-`H` files:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

and once again, your current commit, Git's index, and your working tree all *match*.

To make a new commit now, you:

- modify working tree files;
- run `git add`: this *updates the proposed new commit snapshot* by copying the updated file back into Git's index;<sup>3</sup>
- eventually, run `git commit`.

When you do run `git commit`, Git packages up the *index* files—the ones that are in the frozen format, but are replaceable until this point—into a new frozen snapshot, and uses that for the new commit.  Git gathers or generates the appropriate metadata as well, and writes all this out and now we have our new commit, which gets a new, unique hash ID, and then `git commit` stuffs the new hash ID into the current branch name:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

We've added another commit as usual, and note that now—since the index and working tree matched after we `git add`-ed the files, and new commit `K` matches the index since it was made *from* the index—the current commit, Git's index, and your working tree all match again.

We can now make another new commit:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

and we have a nice symmetric setup all ready for merging.  Note how commits up through and including `H` are on *both branches*, while commits `I-J` and `K-L` are only on `br1` and `br2` respectively.

---

<sup>3</sup>We'll skip all the details about how this works.  It's simple in some ways and complicated in others.  The end result is that the index is ready to commit, and holds an updated proposed new commit with the added file having been changed.

---

#### `git show` and `git diff` and `git log -p`

Before we get to `git merge`, let's note one more thing about these commit sequences: they all have *snapshots*, but if we *look at* some commit with `git show` or `git log -p`, we see a *diff*.  If we run:

```
git diff <hash-of-I> <hash-of-J>
```

we see a diff.  What are these diffs and why do we see them?

The answers are pretty simple: a diff is a *recipe*, of sorts.  It shows what *changed* between two snapshots.  If you take the changes shown, and *apply* those changes to the earlier or left-side snapshot, you get the later or right-side snapshot.

Git can in essence play a game of [Spot the Difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_the_difference).  We pick one commit, like `I`, and put it on the left, and another like `J` and put it in the right, and say: *Tell me what changed.*  Git doesn't *store* the *changes*—it stores the whole snapshots—but by comparing the two snapshots, Git can provide a change-recipe: *add this here line after line 12 of `README.txt`* for instance.  Git shows the change as a series of [diff hunks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37620729/1256452), or in some cases, as a completely new added file, or a completely removed file, or a rename (possibly a rename followed by some changes).  We won't cover all these possible cases and will mostly just concern ourselves with the simple diff hunks.

By *comparing* the files in `I` and `J`, Git can show us *what changed*.  That's often much more interesting than the two full snapshots, and that's *why* `git show hash-of-J`, or more simply, `git show br1`, will run this particular `git diff`.  So will `git log -p`.  The diff shows us *what we changed*, not what's in the snapshot, and that's what we want to see.

Both `git show` and `git log -p` use the *parent* information: to show some particular commit, Git finds the parent, extracts (to a temporary area in memory) each of the two snapshots, and compares them with `git diff`.  (The de-duplication helps a lot here: Git can tell immediately, without even extracting the files themselves, whether two files are 100% identical, and thus not bother to diff them at all.)

But using the command line, we can manually pick out any two commits and run `git diff` on them.  For instance, if we look up the hash ID of commit `H`—or have some other way to find it (maybe the branch name `main`, if we didn't delete it)—we can run:

```
git diff <hash-of-H> br1
```

and that will show us what changed between commits `H` and `J`.  This is a *summary* of *all* the changes in `I` and `J`, and it conveniently *eliminates* any change made in `I` that we "undid" in `J` (e.g., if we inserted a typo, and then fixed it, this doesn't show up in the diff since Git skips right over commit `I`).

**This is going to be our definition of "work".**  The work done, from some starting-point commit to the end of the branch, is simply a `git diff` from that starting-point commit to the tip commit of the branch as found by using the branch name.

We can now move on to `git merge`.

#### How `git merge` works, in a nutshell

Let's go back to this repository, but `git switch br1`:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

We have commit `J` checked out, so we see those files.  If we run `git diff L` we'll see what's different between this commit and commit `L` (backwards, sort of, because this puts `L` on the left and our working tree on the right).  But that's not the *work we did*, not on `br1`.  There's work that happened on `br1`, but that's not what this diff shows.  And, there's work that happened on `br2`, too.

What we *want* from Git is to *combine* the work we did on `br1` with the work we (or someone) did on `br2`.  How do we do that?  Well, we already saw that: we find some commit, like commit `H`, that's on *both branches*.  Every commit up through and including commit `H` would work here, but there's one that's sort of obviously best, and that's commit `H` itself.  That's where the two branches split apart.

So we'll have Git run:

```
git diff <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what we did on br1
```

and then run:

```
git diff <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>   # what they did on br2
```

These get us "work done", and because we carefully picked the *same starting commit*, both sets of "work done" can be applied to the snapshot in that starting commit.  That is, Git just has to *combine* the two sets of "work done".

(Note that if we start earlier, at commit `G` for instance, this still works, but now everything in `H` is "work done" in *both commits*.  This makes the merge work harder, to no advantage.  That's why it's so obvious that commit `H` is the *best* shared commit.)

Git's "combining work" happens by doing this:

- for each file we changed, if they didn't touch it at all, use our version of the file;
- for each file they changed, if we didn't touch it at all, use their version;
- for files nobody changed, use any version—all three match;
- for files *both sides* changed, work harder.

In the *work harder* section, Git goes through the diffs: for each *hunk* we changed, if they didn't touch the same lines, take our changes.  For each *hunk* they changed, if we didn't touch the same lines, take their changes.  If we both made the *exact same* change, take *one copy* of that change.<sup>4</sup>  If we made overlapping changes that disagree, Git complains: *I don't know how to combine these!*  Git says that there is a *merge conflict*.  And, as a special case, if we and they make different changes to different lines, but those two changes [abut](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abut), Git also declares a merge conflict.

If there *are* merge conflicts, Git leaves behind a mess.  For space reasons we won't go into any details here, except to mention that this "mess" involves leaving partial merge results in your working tree *and* multiple copies of files in Git's index.  You, as the programmer operating the Git machine, are responsible for cleaning up the mess.

If there aren't any merge conflicts, though, Git will go on to make a merge commit of its own, using the snapshot it got by:

- combining the diffs
- applying the *combined* diffs to the snapshot in the *merge base*, in this case commit `H`

This new snapshot gets metadata as usual, so it's just like every other commit—a snapshot and metadata—with one difference: its list of *parent* hash IDs holds *two* hash IDs.  The new commit goes on the *current branch* as usual, so it looks like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \₁
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /²
          K--L   <-- br2
```

Commit `M` points back to *two* earlier commits instead of just one.  The list of parents is ordered, so sometimes—though not very often—we care which one is *first* and which one isn't.  That's where the little `1` and `2` come in: the *first* parent of `M` is `J`, because `br1` pointed to `J` when we started.  The *second* parent of `M` is `L`, because commit `L` is the commit we merged.

Note that we merge a *commit*, not a branch!  We usually *pick* that commit using a *branch name*, i.e., `git merge br2`.  But we can run this with a raw hash ID, and get the same result.  Commits `K-L` are now "on `br1`", as well as being on `br2`.  (Commits `I-J` are *not* `on br2`: if we run `git switch br2` and `git log`, we won't see `I` and `J`; we'll see `L`, then `K`, then `H`, then `G`, then whatever comes earlier than that.)

Had we used `git switch br2; git merge br1`, we would have gotten this:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /    \₂
...--G--H      M   <-- br2 (HEAD)
         \    /¹
          K--L
```

That is, new *merge commit* `M` would be on `br2`, and all the commits would now be on `br2`, and `br1` would still point to `L` and would not have had any commits added to it.  The *first* parent of `M` would be `L`, and the *second* parent of `M` would be `J`.  But the snapshot would be the same, because Git had the same sets-of-changes to combine (and we assumed there were no conflicts).

---

<sup>4</sup>Exercise: is this always the right thing to do?  What if the changes are adding columns of numbers (like, dollars to be billed) that should be summed up?  Suppose the change *we* made was to add $10 because we sold a $10 item, and the change *they* made was to add $10 because they worked for an amount of time that costs $10.  Is it right to just keep one $10 charge?

---

#### Already up to date; fast-forward

When `git merge` says you are already up to date, you *are*.  Here's an illustration:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          I--J   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

Running `git merge main` or `git merge origin/main` directs Git to look at your current commit `J`, and also at commit `H`, and to work out which commit is the *best shared commit*.  That means we start at `J` and work backwards to `I` and to `H`, and start at `H` and—hey, look, a shared commit!  The best shared commit is commit `H`.  But ... hang on, commit `H` is *already in* the `feature` branch.  If we ran `git diff H H` to see "what they changed", we'd get absolutely nothing.  If we ran `git diff H J` to see what we changed, we'd see what we changed, and adding that to `H` gets ... `J`.  So there's literally nothing to do.

We can get a sort of opposite situation, and it actually occurs pretty often:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
         \
          I--J   <-- feature
```

Note how we're now `on branch main`, as `git status` would say.  We run `git merge feature` and Git goes to find the best *shared* commit.  Well, that's commit `H` again.  Diffing `H` against `H` will once again show nothing.  But this time, we want to *add their changes* to *our lack of changes*.  If we do that as a true merge, we'll get a new commit—let's call it `M` again—that will look like this:

```
          (origin/main still points to H)
         /
...--G--H------M   <-- main (HEAD)
         \    /
          I--J   <-- feature
```

The *snapshot* in commit `M` will *exactly match* the snapshot in `J`, because adding something (the changes from `H` to `J`, if there are any) to nothing produces the something.  This kind of "addition", adding zero, is trivially easy.  So if you don't *prevent* it, Git will take a short-cut and do this:

```
...--G--H   <-- origin/main
         \
          I--J   <-- feature, main (HEAD)
```

That is, Git will move the *name* `main` to point to `J`, and will *check out* commit `J`.  It's as if you did a `git switch` or `git checkout` using `J`'s hash ID or the name `feature`, except that `HEAD` stays attached to `main` *and* the name `main` "slides forward" in what Git calls a *fast-forward operation*.  Git specifically calls *this* fast-forward operation a *fast-forward merge*, but there's no actual *merge* involved.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update your local version of the `main` branch via a `git fetch`:

```
# from local_branch
git fetch origin
git merge origin/main
```

The above `git merge` would be using the most up-to-date remote tracking branch, which should reflect the latest changes on the `main` branch from the remote.

Comment: I got same message , also my got log show me those remote commits which I can’t see locally it’s like I am rebased on them but can’t see